# How to add url parsing in Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I looking to parse only **one specific url** in htaccess in following format

https://example.com/apps/store/customdesign/shopid/2/designid/Design_10

into

https://example.com/apps/store/customdesign.php?shopid=2&designid=Design_10

I tried following things

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customdesign$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /customdesign.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sure, would you mind to show us your current `.htaccess` style file, so that we can see what the issue with your attempt is?

Comment: I am not using any htaccess code, It would be default. Its very old code which is working fine with php extension, but  need new addition with following changes for specific file.

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is _not_ a free coding service. We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to help you with problems you have when doing your work yourself. So please read a few examples, give it a try yourself, this is no rocket science and you probably will succeed yourself. If you have problems, then is the time to ask here by posting your attempt. Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha, your point is valid, let me add my code what I tried which is not working for me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a Mod_Rewrite solution, so first make sure you have the mod rewrite extension active, then write your URL Rewrites;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    ^apps/store/customdesign/shopid/([0-9]+)/designid/([0-9A-Z_]+)$ /apps/store/customdesign.php?shopid=$1&designid=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have provided the solution I would most-likely use if this were my problem, however you should look into RegEx as well as your specific installation and hosting permissions before continuing with URL Rewrites. Spend some time and do some research!